# Creating a Rails model's child when necessary

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a live site that has many Book models. I've recently added a Settings model that belongs_to each Book.

Now when I'm writing code to use the book.settings method, how do I avoid checking ‘book.settings.nil?’ or doing ’book.settings || book.create_settings’ in every call? The settings model has some defaults I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Earlier answer suggested the use of an after commit hook to add default settings to books. As per comments this is not the problem. I have removed the earlier answer to avoid confusion to readers.

You can use a rake task that will be run once on the production server to fix books without default settings.

Comment: That is not the issue as I already have a after create hook to create the settings object. This issue is for the books that already exist that do not have settings objects already created for them.

Comment: Add a rake task that will update all the books that do not have setting and run it the next time you push your code to production server.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the seed file to do that. If you want to post that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Good to know you were able to get it working. I would still recommend a rake task to fix such issues since you can record that as a one time fix. Seed data is better when you want the system to start out with some information. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you put these conditions on a custom method, and call it instead of calling the `settings`, like this:

```
def default_settings
  self.settings || self.create_settings
end
```

Then you call it like this:

```
@book.default_settings
```

You can check for `nil?` inside the `default_settings` too.